# React + TypeScript format input mask currency

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

I need to format my input value to use a mask for BRL currency

Here is my input

```
<InputAnimation
required
type={"number"}
placeholder={" "}
label={"Valor"}
onChange={event=>setValue(event.target.valueAsNumber)}
value={value}
/>
```

I tried many tutorials, however most shows how to do it in jQuery or JS, and that doesn’t work well for React+Typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I used to fix this:

> <InputAnimation
> required
> type={"text"}
> placeholder={" "}
> label={"Valor"}
> id="userInput"
> onChange={formatNumberToBRL}
> value={formattedValue}
> />

And the function:

```
function formatNumberToBRL(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void {
    // Remove any non-numeric characters from the input
    let userInput: string = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

    if (userInput === '') {
      // If the input is empty, set the formatted value to "R$ 0,00"
      setFormattedValue('R$ 0,00');
      setValue(0);
    } else {
      // Convert the input to a number and divide by 100 to get the value in BRL
      let userInputAsNumber: number = parseInt(userInput, 10) / 100;

      // Format the number as BRL currency
      let formattedNumber: string = `R$ ${userInputAsNumber.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\,)/g, "$1.")}`;

      // Update the state with the formatted value and the user input
      setFormattedValue(formattedNumber);
      setValue(userInputAsNumber);
    }
}
```

So there is no need of additional component or lib.

Answer (score 0):

To format your input value to use a mask for BRL currency in React with Typescript, you can use a package like `react-number-format` or `react-currency-format`. Here's an example of how you can use `react-number-format`.

```
npm install react-number-format
```

```
import NumberFormat from 'react-number-format';

...
...
...

<NumberFormat
  required
  placeholder={" "}
  label={"Valor"}
  onValueChange={(values) => {
    const { value } = values;
    setValue(value);
  }}
  value={value}
  thousandSeparator={true}
  prefix={"R$ "}
  decimalScale={2}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use the decimal separator as comma instead of dot, however looks like it doesn’t support. Any idea?